# How to get the original fileName in response body of react-native-image-picker?

Tags: react-native

I have a requirement where I need to get the original file name while picking any document using launchImageLibrary function of react-native-image-picker.

However, the library seems to store the original file in app cache and then picks it up with a different file name, and the original file name is lost in the process. I'm not sure if this issue is present is iOS but it happens in Android. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same need and also been looking for an answer. According to  https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/react-native/react-native-image-picker/  the response object has an origURL but it is only available on iOS

Comment: there is an issue opened for same https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1569